# How to check the part of file name in python3?

Tags: file, python-3.x

for example

if I have a files:

```
applepie.txt
applejam.txt
applesauce.txt
beercan.txt
beercup.txt
```

and I want to download apple.txt, boar.txt, and cat.txt on internet.

here's the point.

```
if not os.path.isfile(apple.txt)
    urlretrieve(apple.txt)
```

is not work, of course. there are not apple.txt.

but it exist already applepie, jam, sauce.

so I don't want to download apple, but boar, cat.

how can I check all of apple files, and pass the download.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`os.listdir()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.listdir) or the [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html) module. `listdir` is easier to use so probably you should start with that.

Comment: can I ask how to use listdir? just if listdir(apple) or something else?

Comment: No, you pass in the path to the directory. Like os.listdir('/tmp/') or os.listdir('C:\Foo')